# No funcionan los elementos HTML que añado en Google Drive

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, html-select

He creado una extensión web para Google Chrome que se activa cuando accedes a una carpeta de Google Drive. Esta extensión añade un diagrama creado con D3.js en dicha carpeta como se puede ver en la siguiente foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas de añadir el diagrama, también añade una lista desplegable pero el problema está en que no funciona cuando hago click en ella (no se abre mostrando las opciones), es decir, se comporta como si no existiera la lista. Lo único que hace es crear el típico rectángulo para seleccionar los elementos como se ven en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado también añadir otros elementos HTML como botones desde las herramientas de desarrolladores de Chrome para probar si funcionaban pero tampoco funcionan cuando en otras webs sí.

El código de la lista desplegable es el siguiente:

```
d3.select("#divSelect")
    .append("select")
    .attr("class","desplegable")
    .attr("id","desplegable")
    .on('change',function (d,i) {
        var grupoSeleccionado = d3.select("#desplegable").node().value; //Examen seleccionado
        if (grupoSeleccionado=="Total"){ //Vision general de los examenes
            dibujarSpiderChart(data);

        } else { //Vision de un examen en concreto
            var notasAlumnoExamen=_.filter(data[0],{'group':grupoSeleccionado});
            var notasMediasExamen=_.filter(data[1],{'group':grupoSeleccionado});
            var dataGrupo=[];
            dataGrupo.push(notasAlumnoExamen);
            dataGrupo.push(notasMediasExamen);
            dibujarSpiderChart(dataGrupo);
        }
        ;})
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(gruposLista)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.id; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.nombre; });
```

Comment: ¿En la consola del navegador se muestran errores?, si es así, [edit] la pregunta y añada la descripción de dichos errores; ayudaría también si agrega algo de código fuente *(que usted intuya pueda ser el causante de este problema que plantea)*.

Comment: En la consola no se muestra ningún error. El problema yo creo que está en la forma en la que esta implementado Drive. ¿Podrías probar a modificar el HTML de una página de Google Drive añadiéndole una lista desplegable o un botón para comprobar si te funcionan o no?.